# Why does this Miller-Rabin Procedure in Scheme works when the code seems to be wrong?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sicp

I am working through SICP. In exercise 1.28 about the Miller-Rabin test. I had this code, that I know is wrong because it does not follow the instrcuccions of the exercise.

```
(define (fast-prime? n times)           
  (define (even? x)             
    (= (remainder x 2) 0))          
  (define (miller-rabin-test n)         
    (try-it (+ 1 (random (- n 1)))))        
  (define (try-it a)                
    (= (expmod a (- n 1) n) 1))         
  (define (expmod base exp m)           
    (cond ((= exp 0) 1) 
      ((even? exp)              
       (if (and (not (= exp (- m 1))) (= (remainder (square exp) m) 1)) 
         0
         (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) m)))
      (else         
        (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m)) m))))
  (cond ((= times 0) true)          
    ((miller-rabin-test n) (fast-prime? n (- times 1))) 
    (else false)))
```

In it I test if the square of the exponent is congruent to 1 mod n. Which according
to what I have read, and other correct implementations I have seen is wrong. I should test
the entire number as in:

```
...
        (square 
         (trivial-test (expmod base (/ exp 2) m) m))
...
```

The thing is that I have tested this, with many prime numbers and large Carmicheal numbers,
and it seems to give the correct answer, though a bit slower. I don't understand why this
seems to work.

Comment: What do you mean by `trivial-test`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of the function "works" only because you are lucky. Try this experiment: evaluate `(fast-prime? 561 3)` a hundred times. Depending on the random witnesses that your function chooses, sometimes it will return true and sometimes it will return false. When I did that I got 12 true and 88 false, but you may get different results, depending on your random number generator.

```
> (let loop ((k 0) (t 0) (f 0))
    (if (= k 100) (values t f)
      (if (fast-prime? 561 3)
          (loop (+ k 1) (+ t 1) f)
          (loop (+ k 1) t (+ f 1)))))
12
88
```

I don't have SICP in front of me -- my copy is at home -- but I can tell you the right way to perform a Miller-Rabin primality test.

Your `expmod` function is incorrect; there is no reason to square the exponent. Here is a proper function to perform modular exponentiation:

```
(define (expm b e m) ; modular exponentiation
  (let loop ((b b) (e e) (x 1))
    (if (zero? e) x
      (loop (modulo (* b b) m) (quotient e 2)
            (if (odd? e) (modulo (* b x) m) x)))))
```

Then Gary Miller's strong pseudoprime test, which is a strong version of your `try-it` test for which there is a witness *a* that proves the compositeness of every composite *n*, looks like this:

```
(define (strong-pseudoprime? n a) ; strong pseudoprime base a
  (let loop ((r 0) (s (- n 1)))
    (if (even? s) (loop (+ r 1) (/ s 2))
      (if (= (expm a s n) 1) #t
        (let loop ((r r) (s s))
          (cond ((zero? r) #f)
                ((= (expm a s n) (- n 1)) #t)
                (else (loop (- r 1) (* s 2)))))))))
```

Assuming the Extended Riemann Hypothesis, testing every *a* from 2 to *n*-1 will prove (an actual, deterministic proof, not just a probabilistic estimate of primality) the primality of a prime *n*, or identify at least one *a* that is a witness to the compositeness of a composite *n*. Michael Rabin proved that if *n* is composite, at least three-quarters of the *a* from 2 to *n*-1 are witnesses to that compositeness, so testing *k* random bases demonstrates, but does not prove, the primality of a prime *n* to a probability of 4<sup>−k</sup>. Thus, this implementation of the Miller-Rabin primality test:

```
(define (prime? n k)
  (let loop ((k k))
    (cond ((zero? k) #t)
          ((not (strong-pseudoprime? n (random (+ 2 (- n 3))))) #f)
          (else (loop (- k 1))))))
```

That always works properly:

```
> (let loop ((k 0) (t 0) (f 0))
    (if (= k 100) (values t f)
      (if (prime? 561 3)
          (loop (+ k 1) (+ t 1) f)
          (loop (+ k 1) t (+ f 1)))))
0
100
```

I know your purpose is to study SICP rather than to program primality tests, but if you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend [this essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog, which discusses the Miller-Rabin test, among other topics. You should also know there are better (faster, less likely to report erroneous result) primality tests available than randomized Miller-Rabin.

Comment: I know my code is wrong, but was fooled becuase it gives 'good' results when you try many `time`s. With 10 for each prime (the smallest I used for my testing before asking), it gives only 3 incorrect results in a 1000, which explains why I 'always' got the right answer. Sample size was my problem. I was fooled by randomness ;-p.
Thanks for the answer, I'll remember to test any probabilistic algorithm with large samples the next time.

Comment: thanks for explanation. the exercise in SICP fails to **clearly** convey the fact (for us, non-mathematicians!) that Miller's test is still a probabilistic test :). So I also, having solved it correctly, was struggling with flaky answers for repeated test runs and long test sequences :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you still got correct answer, because in each iteration of `expmod` you check conditions for previous iteration. You could try to debug `exp` value using `display` function inside `expmod`. Really, your code is not very different from [this one](https://github.com/satori/edu/blob/master/sicp/1.2/1.28.scm).